# Loading related objects Vs Query join

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

Is there a difference/best practice between using the *entity framework 4 `load` method*, as opposed to *joining via a foreign key*, in order to retrieve child data?

So for example, if I had **Order** and **OrderLines**, should I write a query that uses and `inner join` say on **orderId** to retrieve a collection, or should I be doing something like **Orders.OrderLines.Load** to populate the entity collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends if you want to *automatically* get these associations, or explicitly ask for them.

For example, if you did this:

```
Order order = ctx.Orders.SingleOrDefault();
OrderLines lines = order.OrderLines; // do you want this null, or populated?
```

There is a reason why they call it "**lazy loading**", because your being lazy in that you do not want to explicitly ask for the relationship.

If lazy loading is **on** (default), that second line will silently do an extra round trip to the db to fetch the order lines.

If you turn lazy loading **off**, the above line will be null.

And the way to get it is:

```
Order order = ctx.Orders.Include("OrderLines").SingleOrDefault();
```

Referred to as "**eager loading**".

You should not need to explicity perform joins for relationships. If you have the relationships setup correctly in your EDMX (e.g you have a navigational property called "OrderLines" on your "Order" entity), **Include** will perform a left outer join for you.

You should only need to do explicit joins when the relationship isn't explicitly exposed on the model.

Comment: Excellent. That was exactly what I was after. Incidentally. Is it possible to have a mixture of the two. E.g. a repository class with methods using lazy and eager?

Comment: @hoakey - unfortunately no, it's a property on your data context. However, they're not really an *opposite* of each other. You could leave lazy loading on, and still eager load your entities. But if you hadn't eager loaded, the entity would still be retrieved, just with an extra call - know what i mean? Really though, you should decide if you care about performance of your app. If you do, you should disable lazy loading. HTH.

Comment: I've gone the eager loading route. However, a stumbling block I'm finding a little tricky to solve is how you actually access the OrderLines properties, as it's only a string and so isn't strongly typed. Any ideas?

Comment: A common pet hate amongst EF'ers (myself included). To get around this is create an enum with the navs. Eg, create an enum called `OrderAssociations`, which would include `OrderLines`, and any other navigational properties on the `Order` entity. Your repository would accept an array of enums: e.g `public Order FindSingle(int orderId, OrderAssociations[] associations)`. Then use an extension method on the enum to convert to an include. That's the only way to "nice it up" a litte. Still, i wish they exposed the navs as strongly typed entities in the model. There must have been a reason for it.